# Azure Logic Apps ACI Connector - BackOff state

Tags: docker, azure-logic-apps, azure-container-instances

I am using the ACI connector in logic apps, and using a customized version of nginx docker image that keeps failing with "CrashLoopBackOff" error.

[image]

The customization I've made is just these two:

```
apt update
apt install ssh
```

and built a new image out of that. While using the base nginx image (from docker hub - library/nginx) works like a charm, the custom version with SSH installed, always gets into the loop with CrashLoopBackOff error.

I'm not a Linux/Ubuntu guy, any idea what could be the issue? I have in fact tried this many times and also used the Ubuntu base image to do the same customisation (install SSH), but the result is the same

**Background**: I am using ACI to run a simple shell script on creation. This probably doesn't have anything to do with the error since it works ok with the base nginx image.

[image]

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: What about now? Any update for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To install the SSH in the image, you need to more than you have done. Here is the example:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:THEPASSWORDYOUCREATED' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

When you have built the image, I suggest you push it into the ACR. Then you can use it in the Logic App and it will work fine. For more details, see [Dockerize an SSH service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/).

Comment: Thanks Charles, I was traveling, will check on this and update in a few days